# An interesting sum arising from a statistics problem

Tags: summation, special-functions, riemann-zeta, digamma-function

While answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778237/expected-waiting-times-and-variance-of-waiting-time-of-exponential-distribution/3778760#3778760) I encountered the following probability distribution:
$$T_n\sim p(t~|~\lambda,n)=n\lambda e^{-\lambda t}(1-e^{-\lambda t})^{n-1}$$
This is a PDF for the random variable $T_n$ , which has to do with waiting times at a bank, or restaurant, or whatever. See the linked question for further details. Anyway, it was of some importance to compute the first and second non-central moments of this random variable. This is detailed in my answer to the linked question. But, then I started wondering about the $m$th non-central moment of this distribution.
$$\mathrm{E}({T_n}^m)=n\lambda \int_0^\infty t^m\cdot e^{-\lambda t}(1-e^{-\lambda t})^{n-1}\mathrm{d}t$$
Using a binomial expansion,
$$\mathrm{E}({T_n}^m)=n\lambda \int_0^\infty t^m\cdot e^{-\lambda t}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{}_{(n-1)}\mathrm{C}_k(-e^{-\lambda t})^{n-1-k}\mathrm{d}t$$
Simplifying and switching the integral and summation signs (fingers crossed!)
$$\mathrm{E}({T_n}^m)=n\lambda\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-1-k}{}_{(n-1)}\mathrm{C}_k\int_0^\infty t^me^{-(n-k)\lambda t}\mathrm{d}t$$
Now using $\tau=\lambda(n-k)t$:
$$\mathrm{E}({T_n}^m)=n\lambda\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-1-k}{}_{(n-1)}\mathrm{C}_k\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{\tau}{\lambda(n-k)}\right)^m e^{-\tau}\frac{1}{\lambda(n-k)}\mathrm{d}\tau$$
$$\mathrm{E}({T_n}^m)=\frac{n}{\lambda^m}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1-k}{}_{(n-1)}\mathrm{C}_k}{(n-k)^{m+1}}\int_0^\infty \tau^m e^{-\tau}\mathrm{d}\tau$$
Great! This is a familiar integral and we can use the properties of the Gamma function.
$$\mathrm{E}({T_n}^m)=\frac{n\cdot m!}{\lambda^m}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1-k}{}_{(n-1)}\mathrm{C}_k}{(n-k)^{m+1}}$$
But what can we say about the sum
$$S(n,m)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1-k}{}_{(n-1)}\mathrm{C}_k}{(n-k)^{m+1}}$$
For $m=0$, Wolfram finds
$$S(n,0)=\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}$$
Which is consistent, because since
$$\mathrm{E}({T_n}^m)=\frac{n\cdot m!}{\lambda^m}S(n,m)$$
Then
$$\mathrm{E}({T_n}^0)=\frac{n\cdot 0!}{\lambda^0}\frac{1}{n}=1.$$
For $m=1$ it finds the striking
$$S(n,1)=\frac{H_n}{n}$$
With $H_n$ being the $n$th harmonic number.
For $m=2$ it finds the even more mysterious,
$$S(n,2)=\frac{6{H_n}^2-6\digamma'(n+1)+\pi^2}{12n}$$
With $\digamma'$ being the first derivative of the [digamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html). For higher $m$ it only continues to get more complicated. For $m=3$, the even crazier
$$S(n,3)=\frac{2{H_n}^3+(\pi^2-6\digamma'(n+1))H_n+2(\digamma''(n+1)+2\zeta(3))}{12n}$$
With $\zeta$ being the Riemann zeta function. And for $m=4$ and onwards, Wolfram fails to find any representations.

Can anyone make any sense of this sum for higher $m$? Or perhaps even provide some justification for the lower order identities
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1-k}{}_{(n-1)}\mathrm{C}_k}{n-k}=\frac{1}{n}$$
And
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1-k}{}_{(n-1)}\mathrm{C}_k}{(n-k)^2}=\frac{H_n}{n}$$

Comment: Writing $(1-e^{-\lambda t})^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}(-e^{-\lambda t})^{(k-1)}$, you arrive at more compact $$\mathrm{E}({T_n}^m)=n\frac{m!}{\lambda^m}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{m+1}}=\frac{m!}{\lambda^m}\color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^m}},$$ and the sum is exactly the subject of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3232079) of myself.

Comment: @metamorphy Wow, thanks! I might take this question down as it is sort of a duplicate. In the mean time, how does $\pi$, $\digamma$, and $\zeta$ find its way into Wolfram's output? How can we show these are equal to $G_3(n)$ in the linked question?

Comment: It is basically abuse of notation. Say, the derivative $\psi'$ of the digamma function (let me use a more traditional notation) is actually simply $\psi'(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+z)^{-2}$, so that "$\pi^2-6\psi'(n+1)$" is equal to $6H_2(n)$.

Comment: @metamorphy Oh, I see now. {By the way I like my little digamma buddy $\digamma$ :) }

Comment: Voting to close as [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3232079/a-binomial-generalization-of-harmonic-numbers) after that much time of thoughts... I wouldn't expect another answer to appear.

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks, I had forgotten about this. Question is now closed.